# How to get all order details including payment custmer product and shipping details in woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the woo-commerce plugin can any one tell me the query which will give me the all the details of order as well as use details.

With one query i required all the the data

for example i required the order_id,YOUR CUSTOMER NUMBER,PURCHASE ORDER NUMBER,TYPE of order(DROP SHIP),shipping address details like name,address,state,country,zip,phone number,
now product name,product qty

all this details with all users i required.can anyone help me?

Answer (score 11):

This is from a custom plugin that I wrote to process payments to a merchant account Woocommerce doesn't have online. This is a function that grabs all of the order data and then places it into an array for use. Shipping wasn't needed so I left it blank, but you can get it the same way as I did for the billing info. So I hope it helps:

```
    function get_itransact_args( $order )
    {
        global $woocommerce;
        $order_id = $order->id;
        $billing_first_name =  get_post_meta($order_id,'_billing_first_name',true);
        $billing_last_name = get_post_meta($order_id,'_billing_last_name',true);
        $billing_company = get_post_meta($order_id,'_billing_company',true);
        $billing_address = get_post_meta($order_id,'_billing_address_1',true);
        $billing_address2 = get_post_meta($order_id,'_billing_address_2',true);
        $billing_city = get_post_meta($order_id,'_billing_city',true);
        $billing_postcode = get_post_meta($order_id,'_billing_postcode',true);
        $billing_country = get_post_meta($order_id,'_billing_country',true);
        $billing_state = get_post_meta($order_id,'_billing_state',true);
        $billing_email = get_post_meta($order_id,'_billing_email',true);
        $billing_phone = get_post_meta($order_id,'_billing_phone',true);
        $billing_paymethod = get_post_meta($order_id,'_payment_method',true);


        $data = array();            
        $data['customerReference'] = $order_id.'-'.$order->order_key;
        $data['description'] = "Payment for order id ".$order_id;
        $data['email'] = $order->billing_email;
        $data['INVNUM'] = $order_id;
        $data['amount'] = number_format($order->get_total(), 2, '.', '');   
        $data['gatewayurl'] = $this->gatewayurl;
        $data['vendor_id'] = $this->vendorid;
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach($items as $item)    {
            $item_id = $item['product_id'];
            $product = new WC_Product($item_id);
            $data["".$item_id ."-desc"] = $item['name'];
            $data["".$item_id ."-cost"] = $product->price;
            $data["".$item_id ."-qty"] = $item['qty'];
        }
        $shipping = $order->get_shipping();
        $data["0-desc"] = 'shipping';
        $data["0-cost"] = $shipping;
        $data["0-qty"] = 1;
        $data['ret_addr'] = add_query_arg('order', $order->id, add_query_arg('key', $order->order_key, get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('pay'))));
        $data['address'] = $billing_address. " " . $billing_address2;
        $data['city'] = $billing_city;
        $data['country'] = $billing_country;
        $data['first_name'] = $billing_first_name;
        $data['last_name'] = $billing_last_name;
        $data['phone'] = $billing_phone;
        $data['state'] = $billing_state;
        $data['zip'] = $billing_postcode;

        $data['saddr'] = '';
        $data['scity'] = '';
        $data['sctry'] = '';
        $data['sfname'] = '';
        $data['slname'] = '';
        $data['sstate'] = '';
        $data['szip'] = '';
        return $data; 
    }
```